# Binomial Heap implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a Binomial Heap in Haskell, using the book "Purely Functional Data Structures" Chris Okasaki.

```
{- Implemetation of Binomial Heap-}
module BinomialHeap where

 {- Definition of a Binomial Tree -}
 data BTree a = Node Int a ([BTree a]) deriving Show

 {- Definition of a Binomial Heap -}
 data BHeap a = Heap [BTree a] deriving Show

 empty :: BHeap a
 empty = Heap []


 {- Linking function tree -}
    -- w/ larger root is
    --  linked w/ tree w/ lower root  -}
 link :: Ord a => BTree a -> BTree a -> BTree a
 link t1@(Node r x1 c1) t2@(Node _ x2 c2) =
    if x1 < x2 then
        Node (r+1) x1 (t2:c1)
    else
        Node (r+1) x2 (t1:c2)

 root :: BTree a -> a
 root (Node _ x _) = x

 {- Gives the rank of the Binomial Tree-} 
 rank :: BTree a -> Int 
 rank (Node r _ _ ) = r

 {- Insertion in the tree -}
    -- Create a new singl. tree
    -- Step through the existing trees in increasing order
    -- until we find a missing rank
    -- link tree of equal ranks
    -- atm it's O(log n)
 insTree :: Ord a => BTree a -> [BTree a] -> [BTree a]
 insTree t [] = [t]
 insTree t ts1@(t1':ts1') =
     if rank t > rank t1' then
        t:ts1
     else
        insTree (link t t1') ts1'

 insert :: Ord a => BHeap a -> a -> BHeap a
 insert (Heap ts) x = Heap $ insTree (Node 0 x []) ts

 {- Merge of Heaps-}
    --  We step through both list of tree in increasing order
    -- link tree of equal root
 merge :: Ord a => [BTree a] -> [BTree a] -> [BTree a]
 merge [] ts = ts 
 merge ts [] = ts
 merge ts1@(t1:ts1') ts2@(t2:ts2') = 
    if rank t1 < rank t2 then
        t1:merge ts1' ts2
    else if rank t2 < rank t1 then
        t2:merge ts1 ts2'
    else 
        insTree (link t1 t2) (merge ts1' ts2')


 sampleHeap :: BHeap Int
 sampleHeap = foldl insert empty [1, 2, 3]
```

The problem is that insertion gives me an output that isn't right :

`Heap [Node 1 1 [Node 0 3 [],Node 0 2 []]]`

The insertion primitive might not be correct. Okasaki says :

"To insert a new element into a heap, we first create a new singleton tree (rank 0). We then step through the existing trees in increasing order of rank until we find a missing rank, linking tree of equal rank as we go. Each link corresponds to a carry in binary arithmetic"

Can you help me find where there can be an error in the insertions primitives ?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please reduce the question to a [MCVE] so we won't have to skip through code that's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: You say the output "isn't right"; what were you expecting to get?

Answer (score 2):

From page 71 of Okasaki's paper (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf):

> For reasons that will become clear later, we maintain the list of
>   trees representing a heap in increasing order of rank, but maintain
>   the list of trees representing the children of a node in decreasing
>   order of rank.

Let's look at your `insTree` function in light of this statement:

```
 insTree :: Ord a => BTree a -> [BTree a] -> [BTree a]
 insTree t [] = [t]
 insTree t ts1@(t1':ts1') =
     if rank t > rank t1' then
        t:ts1
     else
        insTree (link t t1') ts1'
```

Pay attention to the case where the list of binomial trees isn't empty. The code there says *if the rank of the tree being inserted is greater than the rank of next tree in the list, prepend the tree to the list*. This violates the assumption that the list of trees representing a heap is organized in increasing order of rank. Reversing the sign from `>` to `<` in the comparison should fix the problem.